# How to create Lookup tables other than using case statements

Tags: verilog, crc32

I was trying a code which needs look up tables. I wanted to know if there is any other way other than using case statements to create look up tables or to store values into them.

Comment: is it synthesizable code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good synthesis tool will be able to make sense of a ROM (`reg [width-1:0] name [depth-1:0]` if you will) and properly synthesize reasonable hardware from it. You can access its elements using square bracket syntax:

```
reg [7:0] lut [1023:0];
initial $readmemh(...); // to fill lut
assign output = lut[input];
```